# How to get the overall size of the database? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I'm having a couple of tables in a particular database and so i was hoping to get the size of the database when the data is dumped into the particular tables.

This is how i tried

```
var db = await openDatabase('dummy.db'); 
int count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dummyTable1'));
```

I know this approach is wrong since I'm getting only the number of rows in the particular table but how to get the size of the particular table?

Comment: put the db path into a file and do `file.length`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will tell you the size of your db

```
final databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, 'dummy.db');

final file = File(path);
```

Now you can get the file size with

```
final size = file.lengthSync();
or 
final size = await file.length();
```

or alternatively if flutter db support it, you can have a look here:

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_count