# Getting app size through flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a memory usage page in my Android Flutter application.
There should be 3 params:

1. Database size (currently using only Hive)
2. Cache files size
3. Settings size (using only Shared Preferences).

There is a way to get this data through Flutter Application?
If not, is it possible to do that through Java by PlatformChannel?

Comment: check this https://www.programmerall.com/article/8898792056/ it shows how to get cache size
and here you can get db size https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709971/12156637

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.